# Can't run my Quarkus (2.7.6) app using docker and H2

Tags: java, docker, quarkus

I'm trying to run a Quarkus app (I'm using Quarkus 2.7.6) using the command `./run/run.sh -dc` and it gives this error on the logs:

```
Model classes are defined for the default persistence unit <default> but configured datasource <default> not found: the default EntityManagerFactory will not be created. To solve this, configure the default datasource. Refer to https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource for guidance.
```

I can't see what is wrong on my `application.properties`:

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=h2
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:exemplo;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:scripts/carga_banco_dados.sql'
quarkus.datasource.username=username
quarkus.datasource.password=password
```

`pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Does anyone have any clue of what is going on?

I tried to remove the `INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:scripts/carga_banco_dados.sql'` part of `quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url` property.

I also checked my dependecies on `pom.xml`.

I tried to run locally and it worked (I think it's because it's getting the "dev" profile).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem just adding this line on docker-compose.yaml:

```
env_file: ../.env
```